Network Error when send file with formData(axios or fetch) on Android. Works fine on IOS
When I try to send some post request sending a file with formData I receive a Network Error. Most of the time the request works fine, but sometimes I receive this error. The problem occurs when use Android, works fine with IOS.
Recently I updated my application to react-native 0.74.1(latest), before the version was 0.64.4. In older version all works fine.
Current versions:
React native: 0.74.1
Node: >= 18
React: 18.2.0
Current code image:

I tried to send with axios and fetch. Same problem!
